# Upload a war Build from Jenkins to Jfrog private repository

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

How to upload the Jenkins successful war build in freestyle project into jfrog private repository using an executable script or build artifactS.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) in your job's scripts to do this. Specifically the [Uploading files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-UploadingFiles) option.

It allows automating many of the tasks with Artifactory and JFrog Container Registry in a generic way so porting it between different execution environments is easy.